# Origin of "Arachnoleptic fit"

Tags: etymology, internet, puns

In various websites on the Internet, including http://www.joke-archives.com/dictionaries/dictionarywords.html, I've come across the phrase *Arachnoleptic fit*.

Apparently all the words in that set (Beelzebug, Bozone, etc.) are all made by either adding, removing, or replacing a letter from an already existing word or phrase. But I can't figure out the original phrase for *Arachnoleptic fit* which only changes one letter of the word.

I've tried Googling, and got lots of pages *mentioning* the word, but none explaining its origin.

Comment: I remember reading the word/explanation years ago in a little book called "Sniglets" by Rich Hall. Sniglets are the funny words that describe something that doesn't necessarily have another word that means that thing. I just Googled "Sniglets" and came up with this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sniglet. That may help you find the book or other material related to an arachnoleptic fit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about a  non-standard usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](http://scienceblogs.com/grrlscientist/2007/10/03/washington-posts-mensa-invitat/), the word was created as part of a competition by *The Washinton Post*, where people were asked to alter a word by changing only one letter from an already existing word or phrase.

Looking through the comments, however, I found *Narcholeptic* given as a (possible) source. The comment also said that the rules have changed, so probably the "n" was moved around as well as the extra "a" being added at the beginning.

Narcholepsy is apparently *"A disorder characterized by sudden and uncontrollable, though often brief, attacks of deep sleep"*. Most websites spell it without the "h", though.

Answer (score 6):

It looks just like a portemanteau of:

*arachno*[phobia] (**spider**) and
[epi]*-leptic* (**falling**).

I would guess the idea being that one behaves as one would during an epileptic episode, but now cause by a spider(web) - or probably, because of the fear of spiders that the web invokes.

Comment: I thought of this as well, but it doesn't follow the 1-letter-changed rule. Maybe it's an exception?

Comment: @Hippo Well, that _rule_ is never mentioned as a _rule_, is it? You deduced that rule from the (quite random) set of word plays on that site, and like every good _rule_, you found the exception to prove it :)

Comment: @Hippo What made you think there was such a rule for inclusion in that list? One doesn't have to go very far down the list to find other examples of made-up portmanteau words, like "extraterrestaurant". In fact I'm not convinced that your "1-letter-changed" rule applies even to the majority of them.

Comment: @Rupe Well, maybe it wasn't *that* particular list; sorry, I should have checked before posting it. But the phrase *did* appear in a worksheet my friend got, and there (according to my friend) it clearly stated that all the words had been created by either adding, changing, or removing a letter.

Comment: @Hippo Fair enough. I see the link in your answer is a bit more consistent with regard to the rule than that in the question, but even there one also finds "caterpallor" which has two letter changes. So I think the answer is probably just that one shouldn't be trying too hard to work this out.

Comment: @Rupe In *Caterpallor* it could be interpreted as the "a" being moved to "i"'s place, and "o" replacing it. But, you're right, I should probably stop trying so hard to sort this out (unless I can find the original rules somewhere).

Answer (score -1):

The word's spelling is probably a convergence to a problem you already know.

The word, I think, is unrelated to your spelling issues. Back when (way) when spiders were not uncommon in (Southern) Europe one could get bitten by a tarantula, an Arachnid. These are rarely fatal but always painful. When this happened the sufferer would perform the "Tarantella" or  Arachnoleptic fit; a spontaneous dance reflecting the great pain being suffered. See: Jumping Up and Down.

Paganini was one composer who wrote music with the title Tarantella, probably with an actual dance in mind but the dance based on the bug bite.